# Sudden increase of response time in Jmeter

Tags: performance, jmeter, operating-system, performance-testing, stress-testing

I run some load tests using Jmeter.

and found out unexpected increase of response time at the end of each test plan.
Just before the end of the test plan(duration 20 minutes), the response time increased all of sudden.

It occurred again when I run same test plan with different duration(duration 30 minutes). and latency is almost the same as response times, that seems no problem on network.

I'm very curious why the response time increased even when the number of threads are decreasing. Could you guess what the reason is?

Thank you in advance.

[image: duration:20 minutes]
[image: duration: 30 mitues]

Comment: do you stop JMeter or is it stopped on its own, how do you define duration?

Comment: @user7294900 Hi, Thank you for asking. I used scheduler and set 1200 and 1800 for each test plan.

Comment: what version of JMeter are you using ?

Comment: @user7294900 Oh really? I should check.

Comment: @UBIKLOADPACK Hi, I used 3.3.

Comment: @Jgj1018 start/end date were removed,not Duration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your screenshot, it is clearly visible that for both cases (20 min and 30 min) response time got increased after the test is complete (duration reached to its endpoint). That's because of threads insufficient ramp-down time.

If your JMeter test is stopped forcefully, all the active threads will be closed immediately. So the requests generated by those threads will get higher response time.

Comment: if you don't mind, could I have a one more question? I got the response time can get higher when active threads are closed immediately. but still curious, why the response time of "application server" is getting higher, not network things. if you don't mind could you describe more details?

Answer (score 0):

See  I am gussing. This happened once for me also. have you checked request are sended properly using View Result Tree Listener. Please check request status once graph getting increasing.

Or

Due to other traffic or Api is used by other users. This my be cause.

Comment: The response status was all 200. I think the other answer is right. Thank you for answering anyway!